# Sequence and progression

Tags: linear-algebra

One of the roots of the equation$2000x^6 + 100x^5 + 10x^3 + x - 2=0$ is in the form of $(\frac{\sqrt m+n}{r})$ . Find m,n,r.
This is a ques in my sequence and progression sheet so please tell a solution related to it.
I tried it several times but not getting a way to solve it.. plzz help.
Thank you.

Comment: $(\frac{\sqrt{m}-n}{r})$ is probably a root too & there is probably a nice quadratic factor ...

Comment: @DietrichBurde You were about 1 minute ahead of me ... good answer !

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* We have 
$$
2000x^6 + 100x^5 + 10x^3 + x - 2=(100x^4 + 10x^2 + 1)(20x^2 + x - 2),
$$
and the second factor has solutions of the required form. I am sorry, but I don't know what your progression sheet is; anyway $(m,n,r)=(161,-1,40)$.

Comment: Thnx brother... But answer given here is

Comment: Ohh sry.. got it... Thnx

Comment: Plzz tell how it cliked in your mind how to make factors.. i often got stuck in these type of problems...